# xsl:sort: sorting double digit by numeric value

Tags: sorting, xslt-1.0

UPDATE : example and add some information.

I have to sort out the number below in numerical order in XSLT 1.0. The "code" follow the pattern below :

for example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DATA>
    <CTX>
        <VA>
            <code>25896_1_1_1</code>
        </VA>   
        <VA>
            <code>25896_10_1_1</code>
        </VA>   
        <VA>
            <code>25896_2_1_2</code>
        </VA>   
        <VA>
            <code>25896_3_1_1</code>
        </VA>                       
        <VA>
            <code>25896_4_1_1</code>
        </VA>                           
        <VA>
            <code>25897_1_1_1</code>
        </VA>                           
        <VA>
            <code>25897_2_1_1</code>
        </VA>                           
        <VA>
            <code>25897_2_1_2</code>
        </VA>   
    </CTX>
</DATA>
```

when I just do <xsl:sort select="code" order="ascending" /> it displays above result.

However, I want that to be in order like this :

```
25896_1_1_1
25896_2_1_2
25896_3_1_1
25896_4_1_1
25896_10_1_1
25897_1_1_1
25897_2_1_1
25897_2_1_2
```

How do I do this?

JAXP XSLT APIs (javax.xml.transform) to transform xml file. With XSL Transform, the engine is Saxon 6.5.5 // https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/trax.html

Comment: I am guessing you want to sort by each number in the string of 4 concatenated numbers separately? Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Yes, that what i want to do.
It's XSTL 1.0 (that the info you are asking ?)

Comment: i find this :
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: I am not asking about your stylesheet, I am asking about your processor. See here how to identify it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: Also please edit your question and show the input as XML - see: [mcve].

Comment: `Xalan-J` and `Saxon 6.5.5` are two different processors - so what you posted is quite confusing.

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. If necessary, post a new question with your new problem - although I believe you should be able to figure it for yourself, using the same principle as shown here.

Comment: Yes, i succed. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, you will need to do it the pedestrian way:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(code, '_')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(code, '_'), '_')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(code, '_'), '_'), '_')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(code, '_'), '_'), '_')" data-type="number"/>
```

---

If your processor happens to support the EXSLT [`str:tokenize()`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension function, you could make it a bit more elegant:

```
<xsl:sort select="str:tokenize(code, '_')[1]" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="str:tokenize(code, '_')[2]" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="str:tokenize(code, '_')[3]" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="str:tokenize(code, '_')[4]" data-type="number"/>
```

---

Untested, because no code was provided.

Comment: Thank you, i edit my initial email.
If my sample can help you, i try to create a good one. My initial XML is so complex and i can't share  it here.

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested? It should work for you. Note that `Xalan` supports the extension function, `Saxon` does not.

Comment: Yes i try it and it's work, now i need to insert it in my XSLT